# Define decorated function without @

Tags: python

So let's say I have a decorator foo() and I apply it to bar() like this:

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

I know there's a way we can decorate already defined function like this:

```
foo(bar())
```

But how to decorate function without syntax sugar?

Comment: `bar = foo(bar)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Generally, the decoration

```
@foo
def bar():
    pass
```

is a shorthand for the following:

```
def bar():
    pass

bar = foo(bar)  # note the missing (); do not call bar
```

The decorator takes a *function itself* as an argument, not the result of a *function call*.

Comment: thank you, that's what I've been looking for. May I ask you one more question - what If bar was defined with parameters? How to decorate it then? P.S. I'll be able to accept your answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: @Desiigner Exactly the same regardless of parameters. The *implementation* of `foo` will have to deal with the parameters. `foo` will (in most cases) return a function that can handle the same arguments as `bar`-